# do something on click with special jquery code

Tags: jquery, onclick

Hey guys I have an code and its work well in the way that I know but I want to do it in another way which I don't know how to do.

This is my code which is work well :

```
$($("#example").next()[0]).click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

The way that I want is should be like this :

```
$(document).on("click","#example",function(){
    alert();
});
```

But I don't know where to add `.next()` and I need it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use another way even though the first one works fine ?

Comment: @Nicolas Because its not gonna work on new codes. (New codes = html codes which will create from JavaScript and jQuery in client side from server side or client side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so easy I found way by editing this code for several times :

```
$(document).on("click",$("#example").next(),function(){
    alert();
});
```